# Stopping the calculations because of predicted error

Tags: c#

I am unsure how to ask this question as I can't quite well translate it.

I am currently working on my own Windows Form Application that will calculate the dimensions of a given package in inches (written all together in string format) and calculate the dimensions in centimeters, milimeters or even meters and at this point I was wondering what if someone entered wrong dimensions and given measures can not be parsed.

Something like Environment.Exit(), but without closing the application just stopping calculations and writing a message that an error has occured.

If there is a question like this answered, please do link it because I haven't been able to find it.

```
namespace PretvaranjeDimenzija
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public double mjera = 1;
public bool pogreska = false;
public string mjeraKratica = " cm";
public string dimenzijeIspis = "";
private void buttonIzracunaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dim = textBoxDimenzije.Text;
    if (dim.Contains('.'))
    {
       dim = dim.Replace('.', ',');
    }
    if (dim.Length != 0)
    {
        if (dim.IndexOf('x') != -1)
        {
            string[] multiDim = dim.Split('x');
            double[] multiDimCentimetara = new double[multiDim.Length];
            bool[] uspjeh = new bool[multiDim.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < multiDim.Length; i++)
            {
                uspjeh[i] = double.TryParse(multiDim[i], out multiDimCentimetara[i]);
                if (uspjeh[i] == false)
                {
                    pogreska = true;
                    goto kraj;
                }
            }
            kraj:
            if (pogreska == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Doslo je do pogreske!");
                pogreska = false;
            }
            else
            {
                double[] dimenzije = new double[multiDim.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < dimenzije.Length; i++)
                {
                    dimenzije[i] = multiDimCentimetara[i] * 2.54 * mjera;
                    if (i == dimenzije.Length - 1)
                    {
                        dimenzijeIspis += dimenzije[i].ToString() + mjeraKratica;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dimenzijeIspis += dimenzije[i].ToString() + "x";
                    }
                }
                textBoxIspisDimenzija.Text = dimenzijeIspis;
                dimenzijeIspis = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double dimCentimetara;
            if(double.TryParse(dim, out dimCentimetara))
            {
                double dimenzija = dimCentimetara * 2.54 * mjera;
                dimenzijeIspis = dimenzija.ToString() + mjeraKratica;
                textBoxIspisDimenzija.Text = dimenzijeIspis;
                dimenzijeIspis = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Doslo je do pogreske!");
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mjera = 0.01;
    mjeraKratica = " m";
    if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
}
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mjera = 1;
    mjeraKratica = " cm";
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
    }
    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
    }
}
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mjera = 10;
    mjeraKratica = " mm";
    if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
    }
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use try-catch when parsing

Comment: Question is unclear: How exactly do you determine that the entered measures were wrong? (But if it's an error thrown while parsing you can use `try` `catch` as @Datsheep pointed out)

Comment: This should be pretty simple, once user enters the dimensions & hit some button which user might actually be hitting to trigger Calculate function, you can apply some validation rules through some function to verity if input values are correct and parse them correctly. With some unwanted values you can always use try-catch.

Comment: @UnholySheep For parsing I use TryParse() method, but what I had in mind are some minor problems that user won't know but might corrupt the result.

Comment: @Mady Yeah, thought about it and it might be the best solution to the minor errors, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple, depending on your requirements.  For example, you could just use a basic `if` block in your method.

```
void CalculateStuff()
{
    // Get input.  Do stuff.

    if (IsInvalid)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You did a bad thing.");
        return; // exit the method.
    }

    // now that we know the input is good, do other stuff.
}
```

Substitute `IsInvalid` with whatever check condition you want that will return true if the input is not valid.

Comment: Although it is a valid code, I had something in mind for future where it will have to stop calculating but won't terminate the program.

Comment: @HR_Luka -- This won't terminate the program if you use it the right way.  you need to give us more details about your application.  Is it WinForms?  Is this happening from an event handler?

Comment: Sorry, if it hasn't been detailed enough. It's simple Windows Form that has no event handlers and everything that happens is in the code protected with few bool variables and try-catch blocks

Comment: What do you mean "is in the code"?  Where is "the code"?  Can you update your question to include all your code so we can get a better sense of what you're trying to do?